# Why have I weird characters in my index.html?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code and when I open my index.html I have weird characters there like chinese letters. I don't know why because other files in that projects are ok. I think that it can be connected with VSC e.g encding. Please help me!

I tried to change encoding but it wouldn't work.

ℼ佄呃偙⁅瑨汭ാ㰊瑨汭氠湡㵧攢≮ാ㰊敨摡ാ †㰠敭慴挠慨獲瑥∽呕ⵆ∸ാ †㰠敭慴渠浡㵥瘢敩灷牯≴挠湯整瑮∽楷瑤㵨敤楶散眭摩桴‬湩瑩慩⵬捳污㵥⸱∰ാ †㰠敭慴栠瑴⵰煥極㵶堢唭ⵁ潃灭瑡扩敬•潣瑮湥㵴椢㵥摥敧㸢਍††琼瑩敬倾潨潴牧灡票䴠⁹潗汲㱤琯瑩敬ാ †㰠楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•牨晥∽楤瑳振獳戯潯獴牴灡洮湩挮獳㸢਍††氼湩⁫牨晥∽瑨灴㩳⼯潦瑮⹳潧杯敬灡獩挮浯振獳昿浡汩㵹牆湡⭫畒汨䰫扩敲㌺〰㜬〰䩼獯晥湩匫湡㩳〴ⰰ〷☰浡㭰畳獢瑥氽瑡湩攭瑸•敲㵬猢祴敬桳敥≴ാ †㰠楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•牨晥∽瑨灴㩳⼯獵⹥潦瑮睡獥浯⹥潣⽭敲敬獡獥瘯⸵⸸⼱獣⽳污⹬獣≳椠瑮来楲祴∽桳㍡㐸㔭漰啂䕈癭兰ㄫ坬礴㜵呐浆䍨塡ば䱍搵〶ㅍ㝍䡵⬲煮楕究敉桢摮䩏㉋愸癮≦挠潲獳牯杩湩∽湡湯浹畯≳ാ †㰠楬歮爠汥∽瑳汹獥敨瑥•牨晥∽楤瑳振獳猯祴敬挮獳㸢਍††਍⼼敨摡ാ㰊潢祤ാഊ †㰠ⴡ䠭䅅䕄ⵒ㸭਍††格慥敤⁲汣獡㵳瘢⵨〱∰椠㵤栢浯≥ാ †††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳挢湯慴湩牥昭畬摩㸢਍††††††渼癡挠慬獳∽慮扶牡渠癡慢⵲硥慰摮猭≭ാ †††††††㰠汵挠慬獳∽慮扶牡渭癡㸢਍††††††††††氼⁩汣獡㵳渢癡椭整≭ാ †††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳渢癡氭湩⁫捡楴敶•牨晥∽栣浯≥䠾浯㱥愯ാ †††††††††㰠氯㹩਍††††††††††氼⁩汣獡㵳渢癡椭整≭ാ †††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳渢癡氭湩≫栠敲㵦⌢污畢獭㸢汁畢獭⼼㹡਍††††††††††⼼楬ാ †††††††††㰠楬挠慬獳∽慮⵶瑩浥㸢਍††††††††††††愼挠慬獳∽慮⵶楬歮•牨晥∽猣潨≰匾潨㱰愯ാ †††††††††㰠氯㹩਍††††††††††氼⁩汣獡㵳渢癡椭整≭ാ †††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳渢癡氭湩⁫楢杧牥昭湯≴栠敲㵦⌢潳桰慩㸢潓桰慩⼼㹡††††††††††††਍††††††††††⼼楬ാ †††††††††㰠楬挠慬獳∽慮⵶瑩浥㸢਍††††††††††††愼挠慬獳∽慮⵶楬歮•牨晥∽琣潨杵瑨≳举睥㱳愯ാ †††††††††㰠氯㹩਍††††††††††氼⁩汣獡㵳渢癡椭整≭ാ †††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳渢癡氭湩≫栠敲㵦⌢敳癲捩獥㸢扁畯㱴愯ാ †††††††††㰠氯㹩਍††††††††††氼⁩汣獡㵳渢癡椭整≭ാ †††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳渢癡氭湩≫栠敲㵦⌢潣瑮捡≴䌾湯慴瑣⼼㹡਍††††††††††⼼楬ാ †††††††㰠甯㹬਍††††††⼼慮㹶਍††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽潲≷ാ †††††††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳挢汯ㄭ∲㰾搯癩ാ †††††㰠搯癩ാ †††††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳爢睯㸢਍††††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽潣≬㰾搯癩ാ †††††††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳樢浵潢牴湯挠汯ㄭ‱潢摲牥爠畯摮摥〭洠⵴∵ാ †††††††††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳爢睯㸢਍††††††††††††搼癩椠㵤猢楬敤≲挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥猠楬敤挠汯ㄭ∲搠瑡ⵡ楲敤∽慣潲獵汥㸢਍਍††††††††††††††ℼⴭ䤠摮捩瑡牯⁳ⴭാ †††††††††††††㰠汵挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥椭摮捩瑡牯≳ാ †††††††††††††††㰠楬搠瑡ⵡ慴杲瑥∽猣楬敤≲搠瑡ⵡ汳摩ⵥ潴∽∰挠慬獳∽捡楴敶㸢⼼楬ാ †††††††††††††††㰠楬搠瑡ⵡ慴杲瑥∽猣楬敤≲搠瑡ⵡ汳摩ⵥ潴∽∱㰾氯㹩਍††††††††††††††††氼⁩慤慴琭牡敧㵴⌢汳摩牥•慤慴猭楬敤琭㵯㈢㸢⼼楬ാ †††††††††††††㰠甯㹬਍਍††††††††††††††ℼⴭ吠敨猠楬敤桳睯ⴠ㸭਍††††††††††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥椭湮牥㸢਍††††††††††††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥椭整⁭捡楴敶㸢਍††††††††††††††††椼杭挠慬獳∽敨摡牥猭潬慧≮猠捲∽牳⽣浩⽧敨摡牥⸲灪≧愠瑬∽楐瑣牵⁥∱ാ †††††††††††††††††㰠楤⁶汣獡㵳挢牡畯敳⵬慣瑰潩≮ാ †††††††††††††††††††㰠⁰汣獡㵳瀢牡条慲桰瀠牡条慲桰ⴭ桷瑩≥䤾琠歡⁥桰瑯獯⼼㹰਍††††††††††††††††††††格㸱湉琠敨眠潯㱤栯㸱਍††††††††††††††††††⼼楤㹶਍††††††††††††††††⼼楤㹶਍††††††††††††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥椭整≭ാ †††††††††††††††㰠浩⁧牳㵣猢捲椯杭栯慥敤㍲樮杰•污㵴倢捩畴敲㈠㸢਍††††††††††††††††⼼楤㹶਍††††††††††††††††搼癩挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥椭整≭ാ †††††††††††††††㰠浩⁧牳㵣猢捲椯杭栯慥敤㉲樮杰•污㵴倢捩畴敲㌠㸢਍††††††††††††††††⼼楤㹶਍††††††††††††††⼼楤㹶਍਍††††††††††††††ℼⴭ䰠晥⁴湡⁤楲桧⁴潣瑮潲獬ⴠ㸭਍††††††††††††††愼挠慬獳∽慣潲獵汥挭湯牴汯瀭敲≶栠敲㵦⌢汳摩牥•慤慴猭楬敤∽牰癥㸢਍††††††††††††††††猼慰㹮਍††††††††††††††††††椼杭挠慬獳∽牡潲⵷敬瑦•牳㵣猢捲椯杭愯牲睯爭杩瑨瀮杮㸢਍††††††††††††††††⼼灳湡ാ †††††††††††††㰠愯ാ †††††††††††††㰠⁡汣獡㵳挢牡畯敳⵬潣

It's a piece of code. I noticed that there is only one number of line  (1).

Comment: To rule out a VS Code issue, try opening this file in another editor. For instance, Vim (`$ vim index.html`).

Comment: File index.html doesn't work in different editor. I suppose that this file changed to one big string with weird characters. Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a question? That would make it easier to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask